# HTTP Callback URL vs. WebSocket for ansynchronous response?

Tags: python, rest, go, websocket

I have two servers: Golang and Python (2.7). The Python (Bottle) server has a computation intensive task to perform and exposes a RESTful URI to start the execution of the process. That is, the Go server sends:

`HTTP GET to myserver.com/data`

The python server performs the computation and needs to inform the Go server of the completion of the processing. There are two ways in which I see this can be designed:

1. Go sends a callback URL/data to Python and python responds by hitting that URL. E.g:

   HTTP GET | myserver.com/data | Data{callbackURI:goserver.com/process/results, Type: POST, response:"processComplete"}
2. Have a WebSocket based response be sent back from Python to Go.

What would be a more suitable design? Are there pros/cons of doing one over the other? Other than error conditions (server crashed etc.,) the only thing that the Python server needs to actually "inform" the client is about completing the computation. That's the only response.

The team working on the Go server is not very well versed with having a Go client based on websockets/ajax (nor do I. But I've never written a single line of Go :) #1 seems to be easier but am not aware of whether it is an accepted design approach or is it just a hack? What's the recommended way to proceed in this regard?

Comment: This is really opinion based more than anything, personally I'd go with the first option where you assign a unique id to each request and have your python script include that in the processComplete call.

Comment: I'm sure it's not purely opinion based. There are just two ways of doing it and the trend seems to be #2. I wish to know how #1 weighs with respect to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how often these signal are being sent. If it's many times per second, keeping a websocket open might make more sense. Otherwise, use option #1 since it will have less overhead and be more loosely coupled.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you seen #1 be deployed as a pattern? To answer your question, the frequency of signals is rather low. Only when there is a (single) response to send. I'm leaning towards #1 myself.

Comment: I've never encountered this exact situation, no. Question for you: why not do the computational stuff in Go? Wouldn't it be faster?

Comment: I have seen this pattern as I have implemented it myself before.  I would almost certainly go with Option 1.

Comment: @anders - Unfortunately, the "servers" were written at different points in time by different people. Although it'd been preferable to implement the Go server implementation using Python (since the compute intensive process was written prior to that, in Python :). However, the team decided to go with a different language altogether leading to this design. The decision was made much before I joined the team ;)

Comment: @sberry - Thanks for the tip. I wish to reinforce that it's not a "bad way" of doing things and hence the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it RESTful, then when the client requests `HTTP GET myserver.com/data` the server should return a [`202 Accepted`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) status code:

> 202 Accepted
>
> **The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.** The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. **Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.**

The Python server could return an ETA and an URL to a temporary resource to request the current status of the operation (e.g.: `myserver.com/temp_data?processing_status`). Then it's up to the Go client to wait for the task to fulfill by requesting this resource and reading the ETA. Once the processing is done, the Python server could return a `410 Gone` status with the definitive URL of the new resource.

Comment: @rvignaci0 - that's a very good and recommended/restful way of doing it. However, it requires the Go server to constantly poll the Python server at some interval. I want to avoid that and hence didn't wish to go this route. Besides this would require I have a rather asynchronous python server to be able to pull this off and a single threaded like model wouldn't work. That is dispatch the task and then send the `202` in an async fashion. Something I wish to avoid. I may land up doing just that but would prefer a non-polling approach. Good points though. I'll keep them in mind.